# Bootstrap Progressbar Programmetic Runtime

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, progress-bar

I'm trying to add the default bootstrap progressbar during runtime. The design time progressbar comes up fine, but when i try to add it runtime using jquery, the progress won't show. I need to be able to add these progressbars dynamically during runtime.

Not sure what i'm missing, is there a init function or something i should use?

Got a fiddle here.
https://jsfiddle.net/riyasdeen/Lxovnbdj/

```
$(function() {
$('#prog_progress')
.append($($('<div>')
    .addClass('progress')
    .append($($('<div>')
        .addClass('progress-bar progress-bar-success progress-bar-striped')
        .attr('role','progressbar')
        .attr('aria-valuenow', '50')
        .attr('aria-valuemin', '0')
        .attr('aria-valuemax', '100')
        .css('width', '200px;')
        .append($($('<span>')
            .addClass('sr-only')
            .append('60%')
            ))
        ))
    ))
```

});

Thanks for your time.

R

Answer (score 0):

Try below Code

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lxovnbdj/3/)

```
$(function() {
$('#prog_progress')
.append($($('<div>')
    .addClass('progress')
    .append($($('<div style="width:60%">')
        .addClass('progress-bar progress-bar-success progress-bar-striped')
        .attr('role','progressbar')
        .attr('aria-valuenow', '50')
        .attr('aria-valuemin', '0')
        .attr('aria-valuemax', '100')
        .css('width', '200px;')
        .append($($('<span>')
            .addClass('sr-only')
            .append('60%')
            ))
        ))
    ))
});
```

**You missed to give width to it.**